# specific wifi network doesn't show up anymore

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10

I have a laptop that a specific wifi network doesn't show up anymore. In others devices, such as this laptop I'm using right now, my smartphone etc the network show up and connect without any issue. Only on that laptop it isn't showing up anymore. Both laptops use Windows 10. How do I fix this?
I tried to create a new entry manually o control panel, it was created but still doesn't show on available wifi networks.

Comment: Does it show any WiFi networks? If it does not, either the WiFi is turned off or defective. If it sees other networks, just not yours, then please update your question with those details.

Comment: It does show all except my network

Comment: Have you told it to forget your network? How about changing the channel on the router?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because, your router has a channel number which your system doesn't support. I also had the same problem. To solve this, you have to go to router settings and edit it's channel number. Most probably it might be selecting automatically. You set that to a lower value. Eg 1 or 2